# Does every topological manifold admit a good or sufficient cover?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

A *topological manifold* (without boundary) is a locally euclidean Hausdorff space, which is second countable (or maybe only paracompact, that is to say make the definition as strict as you like).

A *good open cover* of a space $X$ is an open cover $(U_i)_i$, where every finite intersection $U_{i_1} \cap ... \cap U_{i_k}$ is either empty or contractible.

I define a *sufficient open cover* to be a cover, where every finite intersection is either empty or a disjoint union of contractible spaces.

> Does every topological $n$-manifold admit a good open cover or a sufficient open cover?

All the information I could find about good covers of manifolds involved smooth or differentiable manifolds. On [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/good+open+cover#nonexistence_for_topological_manifolds) it is only stated that the methods involved for proving the existence of good covers in the smooth case don't work in the topological case. No reference to a counterexample or other disprove is given.

Note that I am *not really* (just sort of) interested in the cover being finite. As explained [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92881/upper-bound-on-the-number-of-charts-needed-to-cover-a-topological-manifold) every $n$-manifold admits a cover by $n+1$ charts. However there is no reason, why this cover should possibly be a good cover. The closest reference for finite good covers is (again according to [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/good+open+cover#nonexistence_for_topological_manifolds)) this [paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1969/30-1/pjm-v30-n1-p13-s.pdf) by Osborn Stern. However the connectivity conditions confuse me and I don't quite understand how they replace the contractibility condition.

My goal is to show in an axiomatic way (see [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515019/top-homology-of-manifolds-via-formal-homology-theory)) that for every closed $n$-manifold the homology groups of order $>n$ vanish. I think the existence of a (possibly infinite) sufficient cover would open a way for showing this by induction on the (by compactness) finite number of sufficient opens involved. Of cause, the general existence of a finite sufficient cover would (if my inductive argument is correct) imply that for arbitrary topological $n$-manifolds the higher homology groups vanish...

I would not be surprised, if there is a good reason, why there is no good or sufficient cover in general. However, as I am fairly new to the subject of topological manifolds, I remain hopeful that there is one.

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: This appears to be an open problem, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165850/good-covers-of-manifolds

Comment: As for "sufficient cover", every set is the disjoint union of singletons, each of which is contractible. You should rethink your definition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Topological space are in general not given by the disjoint union of singleton spaces corresponding to their points, as this would make the space discrete...

Comment: @MoisheKohan The "disjoint union" of topological spaces is usually understood to mean the coproduct of those spaces. For example, if someone says that $A = B \amalg C$ for topological spaces $A$, $B$, and $C$, they usually mean that $A$ is the set-theoretic disjoint union of $B$ and $C$ *and* for all $U \subseteq A$, $U$ is open iff $U \cap B$ and $U \cap C$ are open in $B$ and $C$, respectively.